# Query Set for Models Retrieved from External API

Tags: python, django, api, models

I am currently developing a web app that uses the Amazon Product API to get information on books. I use a Book model that contains only the ASIN amazon identification code that looks a bit like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    asin = models.CharField(max_length-10, unique=True)
    def retrieve(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['ItemId'] = self.asin
        self.xml = amazon_lookup(**kwargs) # returns BeautifulSoup
    @property
    def title(self):
        try:
            return self.xml.ItemAttriibutes.Author.text
        except AttributeError: # happens when xml has not been populated
            return None
    ...


class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def retrieve(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['SearchIndex'] = 'Books'
        book_search = amazon_search(**kwargs)
        books = []
        for item in book_search:
            book = self.get_or_create(asin=item.ASIN.text)[0]
            book.xml = item
            books.append(book)
        return books
```

And then I can call it with

```
b = Book.objects.retrieve(Keywords="foo bar")
b.retrieve(ResponseGroup="Images,ItemAttributes,...")
t = b.title
```

**This works well enough for tests, but I want a more robust system for future use.**

What I'd really like to do is be able to perform searches with query sets so that frequently accessed results can be cached. As it stands, every request for a book detail view creates a new amazon API call.  My job would be a lot easier if all the API calls were handled inside Query Sets alongside database calls.  Unfortunately, I've found the Django Query Set documentation pretty cryptic and lacking when it comes to customization.  This surely isn't a rare use case.

**Can anyone provide the idiomatic way of handling a problem like this, or a good resource on the subject?**